# Angular factory doesn't return method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I trying to get JSON from remote server through angular factory. But when i call get method from service I get an error:

> TypeError: Events.getEvents is not a function

My factory code:

```
angular.module('starter.services', []).config(function($httpProvider) {
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];})
 .factory('Events', function($http) {
     return {
       getEvents : function() {
        return $http({
          url: 'http://cronicls.ru/events',
          method: 'GET',
          params: { startDate: '2015-09-03', endDate: '2015-09-18' }
    });
  },
 };
});
```

Controller code:

```
.controller('EventListCtrl', function($scope, $http, Events) {
  Events.getEvents().success(function(data){
  console.log(data);
  })
 }
);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you logged out what gets injected into function?

Comment: @christopher No. How I can do it?

Comment: It looks like you forgot to declare dependencies in your controller ['$scope', '$http', 'Events']

Comment: @SergeyLazutkin that is not critical, is optional to allow minification and it will work either way in a developmentfile

Comment: @charlietfl I seem to recall some of my code not working until I implemented this.

Comment: @whois42 Just use the normal console.log.

Comment: @christopher I do it all the time and use gulp to write the injection array during minification

Comment: Check this - https://jsbin.com/honicajune/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: To allow minification you should declare dependencies in $inject property, but they are still required

Comment: @SergeyLazutkin  not ***required*** http://plnkr.co/edit/GDnvTLxQ9los8YRGpFRv?p=preview

Comment: @whois42 The code you posted here looks correct. `Events.getEvents` is indeed a function. There might be a problem elsewhere that is not in this question.

Comment: I would `console.log(Events)` and see what it is. There might be another injectable called `Events` that is replacing your factory.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the semicolon at the end of .factory and make sure your controller follows after the factory just like you did with .factory after .config